# symfony2 command get killed unknown reason

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

i got a sms cronjob running with my server every seconds with flock

and my script been killed abnormal, why i say it is abnormal?

sometime, my script run and send about 2 thousand sms without any problem

sometime(now), my script run a new batch with 173 sms and there is always get killed randomly

here is the dispatcher

```
<?php
namespace MPN\Sms2Bundle\Service;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface;
use MPN\CRMBundle\Service\UserAwareService;
use MPN\Sms2Bundle\Service\Calculator;
use MPN\Sms2Bundle\Service\Renderer;
use MPN\Sms2Bundle\Manager\SettingManager;
use MPN\DataBundle\Entity\Contact\Contact;
use MPN\DataBundle\Entity\Contact\Phone as ContactPhone;
use MPN\Sms2Bundle\Entity\Sms;
use MPN\Sms2Bundle\Entity\SmsConstants;
use MPN\Sms2Bundle\Entity\Batch;
use MPN\Sms2Bundle\Entity\History;
use MPN\Sms2Bundle\SmsEvents;
use MPN\Sms2Bundle\Event\FailureEvent;

/**
 * This class provides low-level methods for sending `sms`.
 *
 * @see \MPN\Sms2Bundle\Service\Sender::sendNow() for high-level method
 */
class Dispatcher extends UserAwareService
{
    private $em;
    private $eventDispatcher;
    private $calculator;
    private $renderer;
    private $settingManager;
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $sender;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em, EventDispatcherInterface $eventDispatcher, SettingManager $settingManager, Calculator $calculator, Renderer $renderer, SecurityContextInterface $securityContext, $username, $password, $sender)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->eventDispatcher = $eventDispatcher;
        $this->settingManager = $settingManager;
        $this->calculator = $calculator;
        $this->renderer = $renderer;
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->sender = $sender;
        $this->setSecurityContext($securityContext);
    }

    /**
     * Sends $sms to $contactPhone.
     *
     * You should check if credit is sufficient before sending $sms.
     * This method ignores the contact's status, i.e. if it is soft-deleted.
     *
     * @see \MPN\Sms2Bundle\Service\Calculator::hasEnoughCreditForOneTime() for checking credit balance
     * @param string|ContactPhone $contactPhone
     * @return boolean|integer Credit spent or FALSE if failed to send.
     */
    public function send(Sms $sms, $contactPhone)
    {
        if (is_string($contactPhone)) {
            $mobile = $contactPhone;
            $contact = null;
        } else {
            $mobile = $contactPhone->getNumber();
            $contact = $contactPhone->getContact();
        }

        $content = $this->renderer->render($sms, $contact);

        $credit = false;
        if ($this->_send($mobile, $content))
            $credit = $this->calculator->calculateCredit($sms, $contact);

        return $credit;
    }

    /**
     * Sends $sms to all filtered and non-deleted linked contact phones.
     * Credits are *DEDUCTED* here.
     *
     * You should check if credit is sufficient to send $sms.
     *
     * @see \MPN\Sms2Bundle\Service\Calculator::hasEnoughCreditForOneTime() for checking credit balance
     * @param \MPN\Sms2Bundle\Entity\Sms $sms
     * @param boolean                    $andFlush
     */
    public function sendToAll(Sms $sms, $andFlush = true)
    {
        $recipients = array();

        if ($sms->getToAllContactTypes() || $sms->getToAllContactGroups() || $sms->getToAllContactPhones()) {
            $contacts = $this->em->getRepository('MPN\DataBundle\Entity\Contact\Contact')->findBy(array(
                'deleted' => false,
            ));

            foreach ($contacts as $contact)
                $recipients = array_merge($recipients, $contact->getMobilePhones());
        } else {
            $contactTypes = $sms->getContactTypes();
            foreach ($contactTypes as $contactType)
                $recipients = array_merge($recipients, $contactType->getMobilePhones());

            $contactGroups = $sms->getContactGroups();
            foreach ($contactGroups as $contactGroup)
                $recipients = array_merge($recipients, $contactGroup->getMobilePhones());

            $contactPhones = $sms->getContactPhones();
            foreach ($contactPhones as $contactPhone)
                $recipients[] = $contactPhone;

            $company = $sms->getCompany();
            if (null !== $company && $company->hasContacts()) {
                $recipients = array_merge($recipients, $company->getMobilePhones());
            }
        }

        $recipients = array_unique(array_merge($recipients, $sms->getGeneralContactsAsArray()));

        // Create a Batch instance and *flush*
        $batch = new Batch();
        $batch->setDeliveredAt(new \DateTime());
        $sms->addBatch($batch); // add batch increase sentCount by 1
        $this->em->flush();
        
        $failedContacts = array();
        foreach ($recipients as $contactPhone) {
            $isContactPhoneInstance = $contactPhone instanceof ContactPhone;

            if ($isContactPhoneInstance) {
                $contact = $contactPhone->getContact();

                if (!$this->isOwner($contact)
                    || $contact->isDeleted()
                    || !$sms->testTargetContact($contact)) {
                    continue;
                }
                
                //Check if not mobile number, mean not start with 601, skip it
                // if (substr($contact->getPhone(), 0, 3) != '601') {
                    // continue;
                // }
            }

            $credit = $this->send($sms, $contactPhone);
            print ".";
            $isSuccessful = $credit !== false;
            $history = new History();

            if ($isContactPhoneInstance) {
                $contact = $contactPhone->getContact();
                $content = $this->renderer->render($sms, $contact);
                $history
                    ->setRecipientName($contact->getFullName())
                    ->setRecipientNumber($contactPhone->getNumber())
                ;
            } else {
                $content = $this->renderer->render($sms);
                $history
                    ->setRecipientName('General Contact')
                    ->setRecipientNumber($contactPhone)
                ;
            }

            // Notify listeners to handle this failure
            if ($isContactPhoneInstance && !$isSuccessful && !in_array($contact, $failedContacts)) {
                $event = new FailureEvent($sms, $contact, $content);
                $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(SmsEvents::FAILURE, $event);

                // Record this contact so mail won't be sent more than one time
                $failedContacts[] = $contact;
            }

            $history
                ->setContent($content)
                ->setCredit((int) $credit)
                ->setSuccess($isSuccessful)
            ;

            $batch
                ->addHistory($history)
            ;

            $this->em->flush();

            // decrease the credit *now*
            // failed to send messages cost 0 credit, so doesn't matter!
            $this->settingManager->decreaseCredit($credit);
        }

        if ($andFlush)
            $this->em->flush();

        return $batch->getCredit();
    }

    /**
     * Sends a message without logging any information.
     *
     * @param string $mobile
     * @param string $content
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function quickSend($mobile, $content)
    {
        return $this->_send($mobile, $content);
    }

    /**
     * Actually sends the message out.
     *
     * @param string $mobile
     * @param string $content
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    private function _send($mobile, $content)
    {
        $url = $this->buildUrl($mobile, $content);
        $response = @file_get_contents($url);

        return !!preg_match('/^1701:\d+$/', $response);
    }

    private function buildUrl($mobile, $content)
    {
        // $url = 'http://www.example.com/websmsapi/isendsms.aspx?username=%s&password=%s&sender=%s&type=%d&mobile=%s&message=%s';
        
        // Fake sms server, record all the record only
        $url = 'http://example.my/sendsms.php?mobile=%s&message=%s';

        $encodedContent = $this->renderer->encode($content);

        if ($this->renderer->isUnicodeContent($content))
            $type = 3;
        else
            $type = 1;

        // return sprintf(
            // $url,
            // $this->username,
            // $this->password,
            // $this->sender,
            // $type,
            // $mobile,
            // $encodedContent
        // );
        
        return sprintf(
            $url, $mobile, $encodedContent
        );
    }
}
```

and here is the send command

```
<?php
namespace MPN\Sms2Bundle\Command;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use MPN\Sms2Bundle\Entity\SmsConstants;
use MPN\Sms2Bundle\SmsEvents;

class SendCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    protected $preEventDispatched = false;

    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('sms:send')
            ->setDescription('Send SMS')
            ->addArgument('id', InputArgument::OPTIONAL, 'Sms ID')
        ;
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        set_time_limit(1800);
        $container = $this->getContainer();

        $eventDispatcher = $container->get('event_dispatcher');
        $em = $container->get('doctrine')->getManager();
        $repo = $em->getRepository('MPNSms2Bundle:Sms');
        $queryBuilder = $repo->createQueryBuilder('s');

        $calculator = $container->get('mpn_sms2.calculator');
        $dispatcher = $container->get('mpn_sms2.dispatcher');

        $id = $input->getArgument('id');

        // In progress status and scheduled to send records
        $queryBuilder
            ->where('s.status = :status')->setParameter('status', SmsConstants::STATUS_IN_PROGRESS)
            ->andWhere('s.scheduledAt <= :now')->setParameter('now', new \DateTime())
            ->andWhere('s.sendCount > s.sentCount')
            ->orderBy('s.createdAt', 'ASC')
        ;

        $messages = array();
        if ($id) {
            $message = $queryBuilder
                ->andWhere('s.id = :id')->setParameter('id', $id)
                ->getQuery()
                ->getOneOrNullResult()
            ;

            if ($message)
                $messages[] = $message;
        } else {
            $messages = $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
        }

        $spentCredit = 0;
        foreach ($messages as $sms) {
            if ($sms->shouldSendNow() && $calculator->hasEnoughCreditForOneTime($sms)) {
                // Pre process event
                if (false === $this->preEventDispatched) {
                    $eventDispatcher->dispatch(SmsEvents::PRE_PROCESS);
                    $this->preEventDispatched = true;
                }

                // credits are deducted in dispatcher
                $credit = $dispatcher->sendToAll($sms, false);
                $spentCredit += $credit;

                $em->flush();
            }
        }

        $output->writeln(sprintf(
            'Spent %d credit(s) at %s',
            $spentCredit,
            date('d-m-Y h:i:s a', time())
        ));

        // Post send event
        $eventDispatcher->dispatch(SmsEvents::POST_PROCESS);
    }
}
```

and in my php setting, i had

> max_execution_time = 480
>
> max_input_time = 0
>
> max_input_vars = 1000
>
> memory_limit = 4096M

and here is the cronjob

```
/usr/bin/env php /home/ecocrm/public_html/control/app/console sms:daemon -e prod >> /tmp/ecocrm_sms_daemon.log 2>&1
```

i save the msg in log, so i can check back

and in my dispatcher, every success(or failed) will

> print ".";

and i check back my log file, there is ..........Killed

and sometime .......................Killed

how can i check why is the Killed occured? any how should i fix or debug it, the error message is so simple, just **Killed**, no other msg to let me check on it...if you like to read more about the source code, kindly tell me, a lot appreciate for who help with this, thanks first

```
**update 1:**
```

after i google for sometime, many say it error because memory leak, so i add this

```
print(sprintf('Memory usage (currently) %dKB/ (max) %dKB', round(memory_get_usage(true) / 1024), memory_get_peak_usage(true) / 1024));print("\r\n");
```

in the dispatcher **foreach ($recipients as $contactPhone) {**

and here is the results

```
Memory usage (currently) 114432KB/ (max) 114688KB
Memory usage (currently) 114432KB/ (max) 114688KB
Memory usage (currently) 114432KB/ (max) 114688KB
Memory usage (currently) 114432KB/ (max) 114688KB
Memory usage (currently) 114688KB/ (max) 114688KB
Memory usage (currently) 114688KB/ (max) 114688KB
Memory usage (currently) 114688KB/ (max) 114688KB
Memory usage (currently) 114688KB/ (max) 114688KB
Memory usage (currently) 114688KB/ (max) 114688KB
Memory usage (currently) 114688KB/ (max) 114688KB
Memory usage (currently) 114688KB/ (max) 114688KB
Memory usage (currently) 114688KB/ (max) 114688KB
Memory usage (currently) 114688KB/ (max) 114688KB
Memory usage (currently) 114688KB/ (max) 114688KB
Memory usage (currently) 114688KB/ (max) 114688KB
Memory usage (currently) 114688KB/ (max) 114688KB
Memory usage (currently) 114688KB/ (max) 114688KB
Memory usage (currently) 114688KB/ (max) 114688KB
Memory usage (currently) 114688KB/ (max) 114688KB
Memory usage (currently) 114688KB/ (max) 114688KB
Memory usage (currently) 114688KB/ (max) 114688KB
```

Comment: I have seen lot of these "killed" when server had no swap configured and process ran out of memory. If you run your loop for a while, you might have memory leak somewhere. Also check for `fingers_crossed` logging handler as it will buffer EVERYTHING in case you might need it.

Comment: fingers_crossed log? did you mean the symfony error log? i have check it at app/logs/prod.log and dev.log, and i don't find anything special in it.

Comment: the cron run every seconds to check is there any available sms to send and foreach loop it if there is any, if memory leak, how can the 2000++ sms sent without problem?

Comment: You might want to implement queue messaging for that purpose. Check out https://github.com/videlalvaro/RabbitMqBundle

Comment: Oh by the way, you can enable php-cli error log and make sure the log file is writable by php-cli.

Comment: `fingers_crossed` is logging strategy http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/logging/monolog.html#handlers-and-channels-writing-logs-to-different-locations